# Difference between ipython and python on SimpleCV installation?

Tags: python

What is the difference between,

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv python-scipy python-numpy python-pip
```

(from the book *Getting Started with Raspberry Pi*) and

```
sudo apt-get install ipython python-opencv python-scipy python-numpy python-pip
```

(from the site [SimpleCV on Raspberry Pi](http://shallowsky.com/blog/linux/install/simplecv-on-rpi.html)); that is, **ipython**?

Answer (score 2):

[ipython](http://ipython.org/) is an alternative interactive shell for Python (better than the standard Python command line).

It is quite useful during development, as it allows you to quickly try pieces of code, load/reload code from a .py file etc...

[image]